# How to configure Argo EventSource for AWS SFTP file creation event?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, argo-workflows, argo-events

I have AWS SFTP server, Argo Workflow and Argo Events configure. My use case is I want to watch over SFTP to see if new file is created/uploaded and trigger one workflow if yes.

> New file upload in SFTP -> Argo EventSource -> Argo Sensor -> Trigger
> Argo Workflow

**I want to use AWS SFTP as EventSource but Argo events does not support that for now.**

**So, how can I use AWS SFTP as Argo EventSource?**

Answer (score 0):

Since AWS SFTP is backed by S3, the easiest thing to do is to publish events to SQS, and then trigger based on those: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/NotificationHowTo.html / https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/aws-transfer-for-sftp-fully-managed-sftp-for-s3/